# Group action on a completely regular space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, group-actions, topological-groups, separation-axioms

I am trying to prove that $X/G$ is completely regular provided that $X$ is a completely regular space and $G$ is a compact hausdorff group acting on $X$.

Let $p: X \rightarrow X/G$ be the canonical quotient map. So I choose a point $\overline{x} \in X/G$ and $C \subseteq X/G$ closed subset with $\overline{x}\notin C$. Then I know that $D = p^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$ and it is disjoint to $G\cdot x = p^{-1}(\overline{x})$. Therefore, for any $g\in G$, there is a continuous function $f_g:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f_g(gx) = 0$ and $f_g(D)= 1$.

I would like to use the compactness of $G$ to be able to consider just finite of such functions, but I don't really know what else to do. I was also trying to construct an $G$-invariant map $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x) = 0$ and $f(D)= 1$ and thus conclude that the map factor uniquely throughout the quotient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall the following known facts

From [AT]:

[image]

I guess [165, Theorem 1.4.13] is the same as [Eng, Theorem 1.4.13].

From [Eng]:

[image]

[image]

References

[165] Ryszard Engelking *General Topology*, PWN, Polish Scientific Publ., 1977.

[AT] A.V. Arhangel'skii, M. Tkachenko *Topological groups and related structures*, Atlantis Press, Paris; World Sci. Publ., NJ, 2008.

[Chaber 1972] Chaber, J. *Remarks on open-closed mappings*, Fund. Math. **74** (1972), 197-208.

[Eng]  Ryszard Engelking, *General Topology*, 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.

[Frolík 1961] Frolík Z. *Applications of complete familes of continuous functions to the theory of $Q$-spaces*, Czech. Math. J **11** (1961),  115-133.

[Ponomarev 1959] Ponomarev V.I. *Open mappings of normal spaces*,
Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR **126** (1959), 716-718, (in Russian).